# Avoid overlap of tick length with label in Highchart gauge

Tags: highcharts

If I increase the tick length in a HighChart's gauge chart it 'll overlap with the pane labels. I need to avoid this overlapping.

Below is my Highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {   
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200,               
    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    minorTickWidth: 1,
    minorTickLength: 15,
    minorTickPosition: 'inside',
    minorTickColor: '#666',

    tickPixelInterval: 30,
    tickWidth: 2,
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    tickLength: 20,
    tickColor: '#666',
    labels: {
        step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'km/h'
    },
    plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 120,            
        thickness: '15%',
        color: '#55BF3B' // green
    }, {
        from: 120,
        to: 160,
        color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
    }, {
        from: 160,
        to: 200,
        color: '#DF5353' // red
    }]
},

series: [{
    name: 'Speed',
    data: [80],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
}]

});
```

The chart looks like this[image]

and here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Murali_Kaliappan/o294xp0v/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to avoid the ticks to overlap the speed in the gauge, you can alter the `distance` in the label category to the perimeter of the gauge. The standard of this is `-25`, setting it to `-30` seems to solve your problem:

```
 labels: {
        step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto',
        distance: -30
    },
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o294xp0v/67/)

See the [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.distance) for more information.